# Fail async method without throwing an exception

Tags: c#, asynchronous, exception, async-await

Suppose I have the following method, and the code that calls it:

```
public async Task<MyResult> PerformAction(string parameter)
{
   if(parameter == "fail")
      throw new Exception("You wanted me to fail.");
   return await MyResult.Create(parameter);
}

var resultOne = await PerformAction("fail");
var resultTwo = await PerformAction("success");
```

This would work fine - but it would throw an exception, incurring the performance cost of the exception.

Is there a way to indicate to the caller that a task failed, **without** throwing an exception?

Comment: You may include `bool IsSuccess` property in `MyResult`.

Comment: You are missing `async` on `PerformAction`.

Comment: Btw, exception is that thing which shouldn't indicate the operation result (even bad result) but failure. If the code clean and properly implemented there should be as less exceptions as possible exceptions thrown. In perfect scenario where environment suits the application needs there can be no exceptions thrown. `Exception` collects Stack Trace, that's a slow and heavy operation.

Comment: @GuruStron - Thanks, I edited the post.

Answer (score 3):

In your case you can do:

```
public Task<MyResult> PerformAction(string parameter)
{
   if(parameter == "fail")
   {
      return Task.FromException<MyResult>(new Exception("You wanted me to fail."));
   }
   return MyResult.Create(parameter);
}
```

Not sure how much faster this will be in terms of performance.

Comment: I think `Exception` performance will be the same but you've successfully eliminated an `async` state machine which is positive on performance.

Comment: Should be `FromException<MyResult>` otherwise it won't compile

Comment: @aepot yes, I would assume the same, but have not checked.

Comment: Another performance tip: [`ValueTask`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/understanding-the-whys-whats-and-whens-of-valuetask/)

Comment: @aepot `ValueTask`s do not have an `Exception` property, so to propagate failure without the state machine you'll have to wrap a `Task` anyway. That `Task` could be cached though, if the type and the message of the exception is always the same.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Correct. That was about performance not exception. About exceptions see my comment under the question post.

Answer (score 1):

A common solution to avoid exception generation and propagation when possible is to wrap results in outer objects:

```
public class Response<T> {
   public IEnumerable<string> Errors {get;set;}
   public bool HasErrors => Errors?.Any() ?? false;
   public bool IsSuccess {get;set;}
   public T Data {get;set;}
}

public async Task<Response<MyResult>> PerformAction(string parameter)
{
   if(parameter == "fail")
      return new Reponse<MyResult>() {
          IsSuccess = false,
          Errors = new string[] {"Failed"}
      };
   return new Response<MyResult>(){
             Result = await MyResult.Create(parameter).ConfigureAwait(false),
             IsSuccess = true
           };
}

var resultOne = await PerformAction("fail");
if (resultOne.HasErrors) { ... }
var resultTwo = await PerformAction("success");
if (resultTwo.HasErrors) { ... }
```

Comment: When `null` is not a valid result, then I can use `null` to indicate failure.  But, when `null` is a valid result, it cannot be used to indicate failure.  In that case, I would probably lean to returning a wrapper type or a tuple.  However... I was *hoping* there was a "cleaner" way to do it.